# I need to implement a 2d shape rotate function

Tags: c++

this is the formular but i dont know how to implement it. can someone please help

[image]

[image]

```
rectangle::rectangle()  //rectangle constructor
{
    bl.real() = 0; //bottom
    bl.imag() = 0; //left

    tr.real() = 1; //top
    tr.imag() = 1; //right
}

complex<double> rectangle::get_bl() const
{
    return bl;
}

complex<double> rectangle::get_tr() const
{
    return tr;
}

void rectangle::rotate(double angle)
{
    //not sure how to do it  tr = tr.real() * cos(angle) + tr.imag() *cos(angle);


}
```

main

```
rectangle r;
r.rotate(90);
```

expected output (not 100% sure)

```
0 0 -1 1
```

Comment: Are you rotating the rectangle about the bottom left point?

Comment: why are you storing rectangle as two std::complex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your shape to `(0, 0)` temporarily (formula assumes you are rotating about origin, so move the bottom-left corner to `(0, 0)`).
2. Apply formula.
3. Move it back.

---

```
if (tr.real() < bl.real()) {
  float tempX = tr.real() - bl.real();
  float tempY = tr.imag() - bl.imag();
} else {
  float tempX = bl.real() - tr.real();
  float tempY = bl.imag() - tr.imag();
}

tr.real() = tempX * cos(theta) - tempY * sin(theta)
tr.imag() = tempx * sin(theta) + tempY * cos(theta)
```

Comment: that gives 0 0 1.34207 -0.445923. is "theta" the angle? i had to declare tempX and tempY out side of the if statement so it worked but the output doesn't seem right

Comment: do you mean move the center of the shape to `(0,0)` because otherwise you are rotating the shape around its bottom left corner. EDIT: saw the comments, you are correct in your answer my mistake, It seems strange to do it around the `bl` corner.

Comment: @user521180: `cos()` is in radians, not degrees. Convert your angle.

Comment: @Blender how do you conver it to radain?

Comment: `1 degree  = 1/360 of a circle`. `1 circle = 2 * pi rad`. `1 degree = 2 * pi / 360 rad`. `x degree = x * pi / 180`

Answer (score 1):

The formula is basically saying:

```
new_x = shape.point[i].x*cos(angle) - shape.point[i].y*sin(angle)
new_y = shape.point[i].x*sin(angle) + shape.point[i].y*cos(angle)
shape.point[i].x = new_x
shape.point[i].y = new_y
```

angle is in radians, to convert from degrees to radians use
`degree*pi/180` where `pi` is the constant `3.14...`

you will need to do this for each point on the shape to fully rotate the shape by the desired degree.

This formula also assumes that the points are centered around (0,0), i.e. the center of the shape is (0,0) and all points are relative to that center.

---

One tip, if applicable, try and store shapes as points, going clockwise from the `0th` point. for instance, this rectangle will be:

```
point[0] = {-1, 1}
point[1] = { 1, 1}
point[2] = { 1,-1}
point[3] = {-1,-1}
```

---

To convert from `tl, br` to `points` you will need to do something similar to:

```
point[0] = {tl.x, tl.y}
point[1] = {br.x, tl.y}
point[2] = {br.x, br.y}
point[3] = {tl.x, br.y}
```

Comment: im a bit confused. how do those variables match to mine b l t r? can you please write that formula with the variable names I used

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it the way you are. I do agree that the most space efficient way to store a rectangle is using `tl`, `br`, but the formula used in this case does not work for those coordinates without some processing. Which will be good practice :P